# What is the space formed by all of the smooth curves in SE(3)?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, lie-groups

What is the name of this space? What condition (e.g., metric) can be added such that we can have a good space such as a Hilbert space.

Some material about SE(3):

[Spline interpolation in SE(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092456/spline-interpolation-in-se3)

[metric on SE(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231466/metric-on-se3)

Comment: This is called the path space. It is what it is. (Well, actually I guess the path space is continuous curves, but they're probably homotopy equivalent.)